# Unable to connect using the http protocol

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, vps

This is one weird problem I'm having in an unmanaged vps I'm not really quite sure what's going on it always "times out" when I try to connect from my location.

I'm new to iptables so here's the list... I'll let you experienced users judge it

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             <some ip>         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I also installed webmin to manage my webserver, but eventually found out that I also couldn't connect to port 10000

by request

http://pastebin.com/5eS6zmmF

a tad messy so I added it in pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give us the output of `iptables -L -n -v`?  I suspect the first line in your RH-Firewall-1-INPUT isn't quite as permissive as it appears to be.

Assuming you're logged in to this box via ssh, could you also try

```
iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

and tell us if that improves your ability to talk HTTP to the box?

Comment: Worked like a charm, also added webmin's port everything's peachy now, I'll throw in the output now in an edit